# Eclipse maven plugin (m2e) is including unexpected files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working with a maven project in eclipse. When I run with "Run As->Maven install" the jar is generated into the target folder properly. But I detected the size of targeted jar is different than if I build the project by command line:

```
mvn clean install
```

I have compared both jar files and I see that the jar created by eclipse contains files that are not in the jar generated with commad line. All the files are into src folder in many packages. As example: /src/main/java/Dummy/resources/file.pdf

**file extensions included in jar file generated with Eclipse** : bd cer cfg class css cvsignore dld gitignore htm jar jardesc jasper jrxml MF odt pdf properties sql txt wsdd xml xsl

**file extensions included in jar file generated with Command line**: class MF properties xml

I need only:  class, MF, properties, xml, cfg and xsl extensions

I have created an example in https://github.com/RubenPozoMolina/49939684

The project contains src/main/resources/test.pdf and src/main/java/dummy/iddummy/resources/test.odt

with eclipse iddummy-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar contains test.odt file executing with command line test.odt file is not into the jar file

How can I configure the files to be included in eclipse?

Comment: Where are those files located ? And what kind of files are they?

Comment: The project contains a lot of folders. Eclipse : bd
cer
cfg
class
css
cvsignore
dld
gitignore
htm
jar
jardesc
jasper
jrxml
MF
odt
pdf
properties
sql
txt
wsdd
xml
xsl
. command line: class
MF
properties
xml

Comment: Please show them in the post...are those directories needed for the project? Which of them is related to Eclipse and which is related to the project itself ? Usually a Maven project has only one relevant directory which is `src/`... the `target` directory is created and should be ignored by `.gitignore` or by `svn:ignore` property and Eclipse should consider this..otherwise your project is wrong configured / imported in Eclipse...

Comment: @RubénPozo What do you mean by "Eclipse jar file extensions"? Are these directories? Are they in `src`? Could you please show us the project content and the jar content?

Comment: I have created an example in https://github.com/RubenPozoMolina/49939684. Please let me know if you need additional info

Comment: Based on that example your problem is related to Eclipse. Have you imported the project via M2E into Eclipse? What version of m2e are you running ? And which version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) m2e 1.8.3.20180227 installed maven version 3.3.9

Comment: Also I tried in windows and linux

Answer (score 0):

You are having non-Java files in you `src/main/java` folder.  They need to be elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. But my question is why eclipse generates a different  jar than maven in command line and where I can configure eclipse to include or exclude some files with an especific extension.

Comment: That’s why. Eclipse does not emulate maven 100%.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of the files contained in the jar I have modified my pom with:

```
    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.MF</include>
                <include>**/*.cfg</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.xsl</exclude>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.bd</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.cer</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.cvsignore</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.css</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.htm</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.gitignore</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.jardesc</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.jasper</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.jrxml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.wsdd</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.odt</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.pdf</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Now the files generated by eclipse and maven via command line are identical